how can i rotate the base of a image but not the image itself
so what i want to do is some title that rotates around but the image shouldnt be rotating, only thing that must rotate is the base of it to give a example maybe i can say hotline miami 1's main menu. how can i make it happen can someone help me please?
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>animation test</t
itle>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="purple">
      <img src="purple.png" class="cabin">  
    </div>
    <div class="white">
      <img src="white.png" class="cabin">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

styles.css
.purple {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation: purple 75s ease-in-out infinite;
  z-index: -2;
}

.white {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation: white 75s ease-in-out infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

.white {
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.purple {
  right: 50.25%;
  top: 50.75%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

@keyframes white {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes purple {
 0% {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

i tried to rotate the image's as normal but then i see the image is rotating around itself too so i researched internet but cant find anything useful so here i am asking you guys

You referenced an example, but no link to it.

I saw your example. It's just a couple of layers.
I mean you have an animated GIF on the bottom and another transparent image on the top.

 <div class="rotate-container purple">
      <img src="purple.png" class="cabin">  
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-container white">
      <img src="white.png" class="cabin">

.rotate-container {

  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: rotate 75s linear infinite;
}

try this,normally rotate container class is working for rotating the container.
try and tell me whethere this answer work or not.
